# How to access KendoUI Grid selected row Hash Template(KendoUI) value in KendoUI Tabstrip

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using kendoUI Detail view template, as shown in the image[image]

When i click on on each row it opens a tabstrip and displays all the data stored in the ViewData for e.g[image]

The main grid Code is shown Below,

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<EnvironmentPOCO>()
      .Name("Grid")
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
          //columns.Bound(d => d.EnvironmentID).Visible(false);
          columns.Bound(d => d.EnvironmentName).Width(200).Title("Environment Name");
          columns.ForeignKey(d => d.EnvironmentTypeID, (List<EnvironmentTypePOCO>)ViewData["EnvironmentType"], "EnvironmentTypeID", "EnvironmentTypeCode").Width(150).Title("Environment Code").EditorTemplateName("_EnvironmentCodeDropDown");
          columns.ForeignKey(d => d.ServerID, (List<ServerPOCO>)ViewData["MyServers"], "ServerID", "ServerDetailsProperty").Width(300).Title("Server Details").EditorTemplateName("_ServerDropDown");
          columns.ForeignKey(d => d.ProjectID, (List<SynergyProjectPOCO>)ViewData["MySynergyProjects"], "ProjectID", "ProjectDetailsProperty").Width(400).Title("Project Details").EditorTemplateName("_ProjectNameDropDown");
          columns.Command(d =>
          {
              d.Edit();
              d.Destroy();

          }).Width(200).Title("Action");
      }

      )

      .ToolBar(tools => tools.Create())
      .Sortable()
      .Pageable()
      .Filterable()
      .Navigatable()
      .Sortable(sortable => sortable.AllowUnsort(false))
       .ClientDetailTemplateId("template")
      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
      .Events(events => events.DataBound("dataBound"))

      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
            .Model(model =>
            {
                model.Id(m => m.EnvironmentID);

            })

            .Read(read => read.Url(ViewBag.ApiBaseUrl).Type(HttpVerbs.Get))
            .Create(create => create.Url(ViewBag.ApiBaseUrl).Type(HttpVerbs.Post))
            .Update(update => update.Url(ViewBag.ApiBaseUrl).Type(HttpVerbs.Put))
            .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Url(ViewBag.ApiBaseUrl).Type(HttpVerbs.Delete))
      )

)
```

I have a viewdata which have all the details i want to show in the tabstrip, but what i want is it should only display the data only related to the rows selected **ServerID**....there should be a if check in for loop for e.g if(//above grid **ServerID**==viewdata **ServerID** display that row of view data).But i dont know how to access the above grid value in the tabstrip and how to use if in cshtml razor engine. **See the if check which is not working** in Tabstrip code is shown below

```
<script id="template" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
   @(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
            .Name("Logins")
            .SelectedIndex(0)
            .Animation(animation => animation.Open(open => open.Fade(FadeDirection.In)))
            .Items(items =>
            {
                items.Add().Text("Contact Information").Content(@<div>
                                <ul>
                                @for (var i = 0; i < viewDataServer.Count; i++)
                                { //How to get the Top Grid ServerID value here in **if**
                                   @if("#=ServerID"==viewDataServer[i].ServerID.ToString())//#=ServerID should be the selected main grid serveridvalue
                                {
                                <li><label>LoginID:</label>@viewDataServer[i].LoginID.ToString()</li>
                                <li><label>ServerID:</label>@viewDataServer[i].ServerID.ToString()</li>
                                <li><label>UserID:</label>@viewDataServer[i].UserID.ToString()</li>
                                <li><label>Password:</label>@viewDataServer[i].passwd.ToString()</li>
                                }
                                }
                                </ul>
                            </div>);
            })
            .ToClientTemplate())
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case any one else have this issue, here is the solution.
The detail template of the Grid is a client template, which means that all content customizations depending on the master row must be managed from the client. Currently the TabStrip uses server-side logic that relies on a parameter (ServerID), which is available only on the client, that's why the server logic does not work as expected.

You need to populate the TabStrip via an Ajax request, which will pass the ServerID

```
items.Add().Text("Contact Information")
    .LoadContentFrom(Url.Content("~/controller/action/?ServerID=#=ServerID#"));
```

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/tabstrip/ajax

For more advanced customization that require manual coding, you can use the Grid's detailInit event, as shown here:

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/detailtemplate